# php IF function based on a specific div id css property

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a multi-page form which works on the principle of loading all of the pages inside the DOM under different DIV id's and as you progress through the form, it simply ads a `style="display:none"` to the Div's which should not be displayed.

I have a problem where two pages need to have the same content, however as i am using javacript and jquery, i am getting conflicts (as technically, both pages are loaded and the scripts are conflicting).

Can i get a php if Function to say - IF Div id `gform_page_2_2` has `style="display:none"` load (block of html a), and IF Div id `gform_page_2_3` has `style="display:none"` load (block of html b), otherwise load nothing.

How would i go bout doing this?

Comment: i can't understand the problem

Comment: No. PHP can not access div properties that way.

Comment: I see. I know Javascript and jQuery can do this... However can i get it to display a whole block of HTML?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what exactly you are asking but since you have a way to determine when to apply `style="display:none"` you can use a boolean value `display_none=true` and use that in your if.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code. Here, I have made use of jQuery here. I have included each page's content inside separate DIVs in my index page. Then displayed the content of the page upon clicking the menu in my navbar. I hope this will give you an idea. :)

JScript:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $('.nav_button').click(function (){
                var page = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
                $('#content').html($('#'+page+'_page').html()); //display content of div(that holds the content of the respective page) in the "conetent" div
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#navbar").offset().top}, 'slow');  //scroll back to the top

                return false;
            });
        </script>
```

HTML:

```
        <!-- Navigation menu -->
        <div id="navbar">
            <a class="nav_button" href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="nav_button" href="#">About</a>
            <a class="nav_button" href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
           <!-- Here page content will be displayed -->
        </div>

        <!-- This div holds the contents of each page -->
        <div style="display:none;">
           <!-- Contact Page -->
           <div id="contact_page">
             You can contact me through this email....
           </div>
           <!-- About Page -->
           <div id="about_page">
             About me? I love coding...
           </div>
           <!-- Home Page -->
           <div id="home_page">
             Yo! You are at my home page. Check out my whole site and enjoy :)
           </div>
        </div>
```

I hope this will help :)
If you want to see it in action, goto: [www.magcojennus.co.cc](http://www.magcojennus.co.cc) (it's a site that I have created for my college day :) )